# How to manipulate offsets of the source database for Debezium

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, kcat

So I've been experimenting with Kafka and I am trying to manipulate/change the offsets of the source database using this link https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/. I was successfully able to do it but I was wondering how I would do this in native kafka commands instead of using kafkacat.
So these are the kafka commands that I'm using

`kafkacat -b kafka:9092 -C -t connect_offsets -f 'Partition(%p) %k %s\n'`

and

```
echo '["In-house",{"server":"optimus-prime"}]|{"ts_sec":1657643280,"file":"mysql-bin.000200"","pos":2136,"row":1,"server_id":223344,"event":2}' | \
kafkacat -P -b kafka:9092 -t connect_offsets -K \| -p 2
```

It basically reverts the offset of the source system back to a previous binlog and I can be able to read the db from a previous point in time. So this works well, but was wondering what I would need to compose via native kafka since we don't have kafkacat on our dev/prod servers although I do see it's value and maybe that will be installed later in the future. This is what I have so far for the transalation but it's not quite doing what I'm thinking.

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh   --bootstrap-server kafka:9092   --topic 
connect_offsets   --property print.offset=true   --property print.partition=true   -- 
property print.headers=true   --property print.timestamp=true   --property 
print.key=true   --from-beginning
```

After I run this I get these results. [image]

This works well for the kafka consumer command but when I try to translate the producer command I run into issues.

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh   --bootstrap-server kafka:9092   --topic connect_offsets  
--property parse.partition=true    --property parse.key=true --property 
key.separator=":"
```

I get a prompt after the producer command and I enter this

`["In-house",{"server":"optimus-prime"}]:{"ts_sec":1657643280,"file":"mysql-bin.000200","pos":2136,"row":1,"server_id":223344,"event":2}:2`

But it seems like it's not taking the command because the bin log position doesn't update after I run the consumer command again. Any ideas? Let me know.

EDIT: After applying OneCricketeer's changes I'm getting this stack trace.
[image]

Comment: What's the name of your topic? Is it literally connect_offsets? There is no topic with that name in my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key.separator=":"` looks like it will be an issue considering it will split your data at `["In-house",{"server":`

So, basically you produced a bad event into the topic, and maybe broke the connector...

If you want to literally use the same command, keep your key separator as `|`, or any other character that will not be part of the key.

Also, `parse.partition` isn't a property that is used, so you should remove `:2` at the end... I'm not even sure `kafka-console-producer` can target a specific partition.

Comment: getting this response now 
 at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$LineMessageReader.readMessage(ConsoleProducer.scala:292)
 at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:51)
 at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)

Comment: Can you edit the question with the full stacktrace?

Comment: done thanks! before I changed it to a pipe | I actually didn't get any errors.

Comment: wait so wait how does it know which partition to locate if I eliminate the 2 ?

Comment: Read the error. `No key found on line`... You're still using `:` between your key and value. And see answer edit, you cannot have `:2` at the end

Comment: You'd need to write your own client to target a specific partition. Otherwise, it'll use the `DefaultPartitioner` logic

Comment: oh geez how did I miss the no key found on line :( haha

Comment: sorry OneCricketeer still just learning but how would one write my own client to target a specific partition, because this would need to be targeted pretty well, because if I just use default it may not be what I want and corrupt my connector.

Comment: Pick a programming language you are comfortable with, then build a Kafka producer client in it. Or, just continue using `kcat`

Comment: thanks OneCricketeer I believe avoiding kafkacat may be more trouble in this case :D